# Easy (non full) disc encryption

Tags: encryption

There is a long and detailed page about the full disk encryption:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019

But I heard that there is an easy (non-full) disk encryption possible.

Are the official docs about the easy disk encryption?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the cryptsetup Wiki, which is pretty good:

https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Edit: To complete that, the always excellent ArchWiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_a_non-root_file_system

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encrypt a container (behaves similar to a folder) or a single non-boot partition or anything external. I would reccommend [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).
I use it on all my removable disks. It is also available on Windows and MacOS so opening from another OS (like in Dual-Boot) wouldn't be a problem.

It offers you with the option of encrypting a whole partition or to make a container (which behaves like a file or folder that can be easily moved and copied).

When you want to use your encrypted files you can just mount whatever you chose to use and then your system will show it as an external drive.

There are also this german guide on [Encryption in gerneral](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Daten_verschl%C3%BCsseln/) and on [VeraCrypt](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VeraCrypt/)